# What is the longest sequence of consecutive twin primes known to exist?

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

For example a Prime triplet where each prime number is separated by a single even number is: 
  $$3, 5, 7$$ 
it contains 3 prime numbers each separated by 2

What is the longest such sequence known to exist where each consecutive prime number is separated by a single even number?

And is there a name for such sequences?

So say if the longest such sequence was n long with the first primer being p, then the sequence would be:

$$ p, p+2, p+4, \ldots, 2(n-1)+p $$

Comment: Wouldn't the list of all primes known, in ascending order, be the longest sequence? Or is there a pattern generating this sequence you have listed here? What's stopping you from adding $29$ to the list above?

Comment: Thanks -- I meant separated by 1

Comment: @OsamaGhani updated the question

Comment: For $p>3$ the triplet $p,p+2,p+4$ contains a number which is divisible by 3...

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression

Comment: @Galc127 -- my question was incorrectly written -- rewrote it

Comment: @user1172468, your question is not clear...

Comment: For the version of the question before the edit, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Prime_constellations and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstellation.html

Comment: @Galc127 -- let me reinspect it -- thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The longest consequtive twin primes sequence is $3,5,7$.

There thre numbers are actually the only three numbers of the forms $n, n+2, n+4$ in which all three numbers are prime. Any other such sequence (if $n\geq 2$) has at least one of the numbers divisible by $3$.